# Trying to log into site and download zipfile

Tags: python, python-requests, download, zip

I am trying to script logging into a website, and then downloading a zip file. The problem is, the zipfile comes back empty and I receive the below error when I try to open it in windows explorer:

[Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder: '\ROADS_All.zip' is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt292.png)

I know that you have to log into the website with credentials, so I am wondering if that has something to do with it.

The file is also very large, so that could be a factor too.

Here is the code I am running:

```
import requests

#Log into website
site_url = 'https://rdw.sandag.org/Account/Login'
userid = 'xxxx@xxxxxx.org'
password = 'xxxxxxxxx'

file_url = 'https://rdw.sandag.org/Account/GetFSFile.aspx?dir=Transportation&Name=Roads_All.zip'
o_file = 'Roads_All.zip'

s = requests.Session()
s.get(site_url)
s.post(site_url, data={'_username': userid, '_password': password})


#Download ROADS_ALL.zip

r = requests.get(file_url)

with open("C:\Folder\Roads_All.zip", "wb") as zip:
    zip.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Be careful with single backslashes in strings, which can be interpreted as escape sequences. Try a raw string instead: `r"C:\Folder\Roads_All.zip"`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out!